# Spring bean inheritance confusion

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have a Spring Component class as follows:

```
@Component
public class A{
   @Value("${some.value}")
   private String s;

   @PostConstruct
   public void setup(){// initialization of private instance variables}

   public void execute(){ //code that makes use of the initialized instance variables }
}
```

I have another class that extends A:

```
@Component
public class B extends A{
   @PostConstruct
   public void setup{
      super.execute();
   }
}
```

So now the issue I am facing is that, when I start my Spring boot application, class B is constructed before class A. As a result, A.setup() is not constructed, which causes a NPE to be thrown when super.execute() is called in B.setup(), as all the instance variables are initialized in A.setup().

To avoid this, I came up with the following hack:

```
@Component
public class B extends A{
    @PostConstruct
       public void setup{
           super.setup();
           super.execute();
       }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to have class A constructed first before class B, so that I can get rid of the above code

Comment: No. It goes from bottom to top and not somewhere in between. So no. You have overridden the `setup` method and if you want to call the super one, then call it like you did in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@DependsOn({"A"})` annotation on top of class `B`, `@DependsOn annotation for managing initialization order.`

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"A"})
public class B extends A{
@PostConstruct
   public void setup{
       super.setup();
   }
```

}

> In case of missing dependency, Spring throws a BeanCreationException with a base exception of NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.